# Eclipse launch profile - Ask for user prompt

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, configuration, command, launch

I have an Eclipse launch file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.m2e.Maven2LaunchConfigurationType">
    <stringAttribute key="M2_GOALS" value="clean appengine:deploy" />
    <stringAttribute key="M2_PROFILES" value="development" />
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc}" />
</launchConfiguration>
```

This file is related to a Google App Engine Maven project, which I'm using to deploy the application to the online environment.

Because different environments (dev, stage, prod, ...) have different configurations, I'm using Maven profiles in order to manage them.

This launch file works fine but I'm unable to easily configure the version to be used for deploy. I have a Maven property in pom.xml file which allows me to deploy a specific version, but it is not very handy

```
<app.deploy.version>this-is-my-version</app.deploy.version>
```

Is there a way to configure .launch file on asking an user input and then configure that input as a Maven property related to the goal I'm using?

---

**EDIT**
I will now generalize and better focus the question:

during a Maven build, does exists a plugin or something that asks for an user input directly from the CLI where the build is running? And can this input be configured as a Maven property which can be used right after while the build is running?

This can be a very generic plugin, a parameter in the goal defines the name of property to be configured with the given input.

Related to my need, an user input will be the version of deployment, and need to be configured as `app.deploy.version` during build.

Something like:

```
...
...
insert value for property 'app.deploy.project'
input: my-value
'app.deploy.project' set to 'my-value'
...
...
```

Comment: Do you want to set the version name during each deployment for Eclipse? This seems to be available in [the current interface](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploying#deploy_the_project_to_gae_name_short).

Comment: You are correct, I want to set a version name during each deploy, but using Maven CLI. I already know about the Eclipse plugin which provides an UI, but is not handy when I'm dealing with Maven profiles. I need to activate/deactive the proper one basing on the environment  I'm deploying.
I now edited the question to better focus on the specific inquiry

Answer (score 0):

Maven profiles are able to set Maven properties.  For example, the following profile sets the `os-jvm-flag` property when the build is run on MacOS.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>macosx-jvm-flags</id>
    <activation>
      <os><family>mac</family></os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <os-jvm-flags>-XstartOnFirstThread</os-jvm-flags>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

If you want to prompt for a version wehen using the Maven launcher from Eclipse, you might be able to use Eclipse's *variable expressions*.  Add a parameter to the Maven launcher page that uses a variable and specify a `string_prompt` expression.

[image: variable expressions]